# How to query postgres incremental updates since a specified point (a timestamp or a transaction id)?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I want to be able to find out incremental changes of postgresql tables.

I know I could use timestamp method: add a timestamp column, and when a row is updated, I could save a timestamp with it, and then could query rows changed after a specified timestamp. Database trigger is not an option for me for some reason, and if don't use database trigger, I have to generate timestamp on web servers, which needs to use NTP to control the time tolerance between servers, and this is also not an option for me as I don't have the control of the servers.

So I'm turning to another solution: select rows that are modified after a specified transaction id. In Postgres txid_current() could return the current transaction id, and I could get incremental updates by sql "select * from table_name where xmin > {transaction_id}".

After some simple testing I find it works. One known issue is that the transaction id will grow over time and one day will needs to reset by postgres, but I'm considering to temporarily disable the incremental updates feature when transaction id is approaching the max value and re-enabling it after the reset is done.

The question is:  I'm not sure if transaction id and xmin could be reliably used to detect incremental changes (except the known transaction_id overflow/reset issue).

Thanks for any suggestions on incremental updates. Maybe there're some other ways to query incremental updates.

Comment: You can't get incremental changes using only the txid because you can't "see" deleted rows that way.

Comment: As my comment in your answer below, my records don't get deleted. Are there other reasons ?

Comment: If all your tables have a serial (surrogate) key, you could use that as a *highwatermark*. Otherwise you could *add* a serial to your tables. (Note: doesn't work for updates, obviously)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really want is PostgreSQL 9.4's [logical decoding](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding.html) support, which lets you extract a *change stream* from the server. To use it you need a logical decoding plugin that turns the change stream on the server into something your app can consume. There are a number in development, but it's still pretty early.

Since you noted in a comment that you're using AWS RDS, at this time you're out of luck, since RDS at time of writing doesn't offer any decoding plugins and you'd need superuser privileges to install them.

You cannot use xmin and xmax for complete incremental copying, because you can't do dirty reads in PostgreSQL, so you can't see if a tuple has been `DELETE`d. To use transaction IDs you'd need to prevent `VACUUM` from removing "dead" rows, i.e. rows that no current transaction still needs to perform correctly. You'd also need to be able to do dirty reads. Neither of those have easy solutions in PostgreSQL.

If you have *insert-only tables* (or you do inserts and updates, never deletes, and never change the primary key of a row) then you can possibly use the transaction xmin. You will have to deal with [transaction-id wraparound](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) by checking `pg_database.datfrozenxid` and `pg_class.relfrozenxid` for the relation of interest. See the source code and comments in the code for details. `VACUUM` and the lack of dirty reads isn't a problem if you never delete an entry, since you don't need to see "vanished" rows.

Use logical decoding in 9.4+ if possible. For older versions if you need complete replication you need to accumulate a change queue with triggers.

If you can prohibit deletes and primary key changes completely you can use `xmin` to find changed rows, so long as you take care to ensure there are no `delete`s run, or any `update`s that change `primary key`s.

Comment: Logical decoding sounds heavy to my application.

Comment: And in my application a row never gets deleted, it's just updated, so I think just xmin is enough. can you point me to some documentation of VACUUM removing dead rows?

Comment: The PostgreSQL manual covers VACUUM. Logical decoding will be the fastest and most efficient way to do what you want, but generic output plugins aren't really mature and widely available yet, so it's not ideal. If you're *absolutely* update-and-insert-only, you can possibly get away with using xmin alone, but you have to deal very carefully with txid wraparound and make sure to check the database frozen xid. Expect to be reading source code and developer documentation if you're going to do this, you're fiddling with database internals directly.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I now know that directly working with txid is "dangerous". txid wraparound and frozen id you mentioned,  are they not in documentation?

Comment: @youlun Probably, but I'm not sure exactly where. They should be covered somewhere, since xid wraparound and freezing (automatically or via `VACUUM FREEZE`) is relevant to admins. Google should help. I really recommend using the logical decoding facility that's *designed to do just what you want to do*. Look into existing logical decoding plugins.

Comment: Sadly I'm using aws postgres which seems to be version 8.4, but I'll learn logic decoding to see what it can do, just for future use. I found the wraparound and freezing here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND, and VACUUM here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-vacuum.html. For future reference, the sql is something like "select * from users where age(xmin) < age('1738641'::xid);".

Comment: AWS RDS PostgreSQL offers PostgreSQL 9.4, which supports logical decoding, but AWS doesn't offer any decoding plugins and you can't install them yourself on RDS, so you can't use logical decoding on RDS at the moment. If you're using Redshift then it's not really PostgreSQL at all but it's closer to PostgreSQL 8.0 or 8.2 in functionality. Either way you can't use logical decoding. So you'll have to use triggers or hack around with xmin/xmax.

Comment: Updated post with info on using xmin/xmax

Comment: Thanks, the update made it more clear. @CraigRinger, I checked related docs and did some experiments on 9.4, I think for my update-only case, seems there's nothing to worry about. The age(::xid) function can handle the wraparound compare correctly. In an article I see that xid=2 is the FrozenXID, so I tried "select age('2'::xid);", it returned 2^31-1, which means it's the oldest transaction if compared using age function. Could you elaborate on "deal with transaction-id wraparound" you mentioned in post, if I still did not get it right?

Comment: @youlun Using `age` is perfect. I honestly forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I'll go this way. Will report any issue if it sadly happens .

Comment: I would like to consider your solution for insert-only tables, but I am concerned about the "*[Note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND): In PostgreSQL versions before 9.4, freezing was implemented by actually replacing a row's insertion XID with `FrozenTransactionId`, which was visible in the row's `xmin` system column. Newer versions just set a flag bit, preserving the row's original `xmin` for possible forensic use.*" Is there a way to check/ensure that an `xmin` refers to a recent transaction and not a frozen one from before a wraparound?

Comment: Not reliably, and on newer versions you'd have to check the page epoch counter to properly sort them too. I don't think newer Pg exposes the tuple xid in a way that's easily compared to `txid_current`, you'd probably have to write a C function. Really, use logical decoding, that's what it's for.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for the great info. in post-9.4 pg that we can't use `xmin` for sync purpose anymore, does `logical decoding` supports syn c scenario? e.g: mobile client downloads all data to his device. after a week he wants to download only the changes into his device. each mobile client synced to a different point of time.

Comment: @CraigRinger Why can't we just save the `txid_current` value on every row? which is int64 value and would "never" wrapped around?

Comment: @Michael Because xids are assigned near the start of a txn, when it does its first write. Txns aren't guaranteed to commit in ascending xid order. I think it might be possible to do by using postgres's info on the current tx's visible snapshot but I wouldn't bet on it without a lot of verification. It's further complicated by the fact that the WAL record for a commit isn't guaranteed to be written in the same order as the commit becomes visible in shared memory so you can have ordering issues on crash and recovery if not careful.

Comment: What we really need is some way to construct a slot that can spool a differential change set. Currently you can only read an incremental change steam. But handling differential change sets is super hard even before you consider DDL; I'm not at all sure how we'd do it.

Comment: Also to be clear you could never correctly use xmin for sync purposes. It would just appear to work most of the time while introducing subtle accumulating data errors due to concurrency between commits. Simplistic test cases would work then it'd fall over in production under load. So don't do that.

Comment: Before you try it, you can't use 9.4+'s commit timestamps feature either. Commit timestamps are not guaranteed to be strictly monotonic in commit order because IIRC the timestamp is collected before the LWLock-protected sections that do the WAL write and the PGXACT shmem update. They're also subject to the limitations of host clock resolution.

Comment: In short - logical decoding was added for a reason.

Comment: You *can* add your own monotonic-by-commit-order counter by the way. You'll just have to serialise your commits. Bad for performance but very simple to do using a row "FOR UPDATE" lock.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the insightful comments! I opened a new, more specific, question about this issue for better reference and it gives more information that may change your answer in my case, I hope you could put some time to answer there as well: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269568/208871 thanks!