# Reliable, low-contention strategy for incrementing a counter column on insert and update

Tags: postgresql, counter, contention

I've got a remedial question regarding sequences. I've used them a bit and consulted the docs, and am hoping that this is an easy question for the group. We're on Postgres 11.4 now, and will move to PG 12 whenever it's available on RDS.

The goal is to have a set of numbers that increase every time a row is inserted or updated. We use the field name "con_id" (concurrency ID) for this kind of counter. So the first time a row is inserted in an empty table, the value is 1, the second row gets 2, etc. Sounds like a `SEQUENCE`. I had a standard sequence in this role, then switched to `AS IDENTITY`...but realize now that was probably a mistake.

On update, the counter should keep working. So, if the first row is updated, the con_id changes from 1 to 3, the `current max()+1`. For the record, all of our updates use `ON CONFLICT(id) SET`, not just a straight `UPDATE`.

The point of the number series is to define start-stop bounds for various operations:

```
operation     last_number_processed
sync_to_domo  124556
rollup_day    123516
rollup_week   103456
```

Then, when it's time to perform one of these operations, all you need to do to find the right chunk of records is select con_id from last_number_processed+1 through max(con_id). You have to update the operation tracker with that max(con_id) once the operation completes.

```
select max(con_id) from source_data; -- Get the current highest number.
```

The range is then something like 124557-128923 for "sync_to_domo".

Uniqueness isn't required here, although it is desirable. Gaps don't matter at all. Keeping the numbers in sequence is essential.

This kind of operation on update is the sort of thing that could easily be a horrific bottleneck, if I botched it. Can anyone suggest the best reliable, low-contention strategy for maintaining a counter that gets the max value from the table +1 on each insert or update?

And, yes, a timestamptz can be used for this purpose, it's just another kind of number line. The reason for an integer is to match how we code other systems. It's just easier to explain and reason about this stuff when the data type remains the same across platforms. Or so it seems, in this case.

## Test Code

I'm adding some test code and results to my original question. This works, but I doubt it's super efficient. The test below is a minimal version, and not useful...I'm just trying to determine if I can get an ever-increasing number line of insertions and revisions. This effort looks okay on a quick check, but there's so much that I do not have internalized about Postgres' approach to contention, that I'm including it mostly so that people can tell me why it's terrible. So, please do ;-)

The setup is to have a sequence that's assigned automatically on `INSERT` and via per `ROW` trigger on `UPDATE`. Sounds less than idea, is there a better way? It works in a single-connection test, but double-increments the counters on `UPDATE`. That's not a problem for me, but I do not understand why it is happening.

Here's the stand-alone test code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data.test_con_ids;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS test_con_ids_sequence;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS data.test_con_ids_update;

BEGIN;
CREATE SEQUENCE data.test_con_ids_sequence 
   AS bigint;

CREATE TABLE data.test_con_ids (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    con_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('test_con_ids_sequence'),
    dts timestamptz default NOW()
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.test_con_ids_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    NEW.con_id := NEXTVAL ('test_con_ids_sequence');
 RETURN NEW;
END
$function$;

    -- It's late here, not sure if I could use a FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger here, which should be faster. If it would work.
    CREATE TRIGGER test_con_ids_update_trigger  BEFORE UPDATE ON data.test_con_ids
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_con_ids_update();

-- Add ten records, IDs 1-10, con_ids 1-10.     
    INSERT INTO data.test_con_ids (id) 
          VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

-- Update rows 1-5 to their current values. The trigger should increment the con_id.   
    INSERT INTO data.test_con_ids (id) 
          VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
          ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE set id = EXCLUDED.id; -- Completely pointless, obviously...just a test. We always UPSERT with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE.

    COMMIT;
```

And here are the results:

```
id  con_id  dts
1   12  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
2   14  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
3   16  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
4   18  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
5   20  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
6   6   2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
7   7   2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
8   8   2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
9   9   2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
10  10  2019-11-02 21:52:34.333926+11
```

That works, 1-10 are created, 1-5 are updated and get their con_id counter values increment. By 2 for some reason (?), but at least they're in a useful order, which is what we need.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to get this behavior more efficiently? The goal is an ever-increasing number line for records reflecting last `INSERT` and `UPDATE` activities. And, because we use integers for this everywhere else, we're trying to stick with integers instead of timestamps. But, honestly, that's cosmetic in a lot of ways. Another reason I'm looking at `SEQUENCE` is that, unless I've misunderstood, it's not bound up in the transaction. That's perfect for this...we don't need a gapless number series, just a sequential one.

## Postgres 12 Test

Following on Belayer's suggestion, I created a PG 12 database as an experiment. I went with the defaults, so everything is in `public`. (In the real world, I strip out `public`.) Yes, a generated column seems to work, so long as you have an immutable function. I've read about `IMMUTABLE` in Postgres several times....and I don't get it. So, I can't say that this function is safe. Seems like it should be. I followed the patterns used in this worthwhile piece:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/generated-columns-in-postgresql-12/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_concurrency_id() RETURNS bigint
AS $$
    SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp())::bigint; 
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.generate_concurrency_id() IS 'Generate a bigint to act as a progressive change counter for a table.';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test_con_ids;
CREATE TABLE test_con_ids (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    con_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (generate_concurrency_id()) STORED,
    dts timestamptz default NOW()
);

-- Add ten records, IDs 1-10, con_ids 1-10.     
    INSERT INTO public.test_con_ids (id) 
          VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

-- Unless you wait here, the con_ids all look the same...this operation is way too short to tick over to another second, unless you get lucky.
-- Update rows 1-5 to their current values. The trigger should increment the con_id.   
    INSERT INTO public.test_con_ids (id) 
          VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
          ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE set id = EXCLUDED.id; -- Completely pointless, obviously...just a test. We always UPSERT with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE.
```

The example above does work with the generated column, but I don't know about the performance characteristics of PG 12 calculated columns vs. triggers.

On a sadder note, I'm thinking that this might not work out for me at all. I *really* need a commit time stamp, which is only available through logical decoding. Here's why, through an example.

- I'm summarizing data and want to grab unprocessed updated or inserted rows.
- The last number I got is from a record added at 01:00:00 AM. Now I want to get all higher numbers.
- Okay...I do that.
- Oh wait, an incomplete transaction comes in and commits timestamps/derived numbers from earlier.

A `SEQUENCE` doesn't really work here either because, again, the row/tuple isn't visible to my collector process until after the transaction commits.

So I think it's logical decoding, an update summary table, or bust.

Comment: Might the [`xmin` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) be a solution?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't know...but I doubt it, but I definitely don't know for sure. some time back, I looked in `track_commit_timestamp`, and that wasn't quite suitable...but sounded pretty close. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961111/questions-about-postgres-track-commit-timestamp-pg-xact-commit-timestamp

Seems like there ought to be a PG 11 or PG 12 feature to get what amounts to a sequence that fires on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, but maybe there's nothing short of a trigger....or maybe a PG 12 generated column?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link. I would have suggested using the plain transaction ids, not their associated timestamps, but apparently then you'd have even larger issues with wraparound. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/32836324/1048572 is of interest?

Comment: Nice link, yes, that's quite a similar problem to mine. I do limited deletion, and never ever change PK values. (We're using UUIDs as our data is collected from a bunch of unconnected servers. Postgres is the only global bit.) I could use DTS values, but you still potentially get messed up by transaction commit order. Hmmm.

Comment: I've updated my question with some test code...hopefully, there's a better way than what I've shown.

Comment: How about the epoch from the clock_timestamp(). So select (extract(epoch from clock_timestamp())*1000000)::bigint. Note 6 digits is the limit of my servers resolution. If you server accomodates more increase the multiplication factor?

Comment: That's a good suggestion as it leaves us with a number. And `now()` would be sufficient for our purposes as the con_id represents sequence, not identity. 

But is there a way to do this without a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger on `UPDATE`?

Comment: I cannot think of any current for version 11 and below. But you indicated you planned to update to 12 when available. Well 12 was released Oct 2019. It implements [virtual column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). You would then define your column as "col_id generated always as (extract(epoch from clock_timestamp())*1000000)::bigint) stored". At least that appears to be how, I don't have 12 up and running as yet so cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

## The Sad and Terrible Truth

I've realized that I'm being clueless about transactions, and that none of these schemes can work. Not only can't this work for `UPDATE`, it can't work for `INSERT` either, which is a bit of a surprise. If I've got something wrong here, please tell me where.

As a thought experiment, imagine three concurrent, uncommitted transactions on a table where the concurrency_id number is incremented on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Here's a simple picture.

[image]

Now, what is the `max(concurrency_id)` in the table? It's meaningless as none of the transactions have committed yet. If you're using a `sequence`, you could grab the `nextval` and then know that anything with a lower number is "earlier". Okay, imagine I use `max` in production, what do I get? It depends *both* on when I ask, and what order/state the transactions are in. Here's a little truth table with outcomes for `max()` and `nextval()` under the various combinations:

```
Scenario    T1            T2            T3            Nextval()   Max()
1           Committed     Committed     Committed     16             15
2           Committed     Committed     Open          16             10
3           Committed     Open          Committed     16             15
4           Committed     Open          Open          16              5
5           Open          Committed     Committed     16             15
6           Open          Committed     Open          16             10
7           Open          Open          Committed     16             15
8           Open          Open          Open          16              0
```

The whole goal here is to lay down markers on the number line (or timeline) to bracket out already processed rows. The processed status isn't a property of the rows, as the same rows can be used in many operations. Such as multiple rollups, sync to various sources, archiving, etc.

If I want to know what to process, I need the last processed value, 0/NULL at the start, and the maximum value to process. If I run the check in scenarios 1, 3, 5, or 7, I get the same max value, 15. However, the committed records at that point vary

```
Scenario    T1            T2            T3            Nextval()   Max()    Values
1           Committed     Committed     Committed     16             15    1-15
3           Committed     Open          Committed     16             15    1-5 and 11-15
5           Open          Committed     Committed     16             15    6-15
7           Open          Open          Committed     16             15    11-15
```

In every case, the processing window tracker stores the max value, 15 in each case. No harm so far. But what happens when I next run my check, and want to find all of the unprocessed rows the next time? They look staring at > 16. The net result is that only scenario 1 works, all of the others end up with records with earlier numbers/timestamps committing *after* I ran my check, and so those numbers are never going to be captured. As far as I can tell, using a sequence can't help. While a sequence is not transaction-bound, the *row* it represents is transaction bound. And timestamps don't help as there is no timestamp-in-actual-commit-order function available.

I think that the only solution (as I think others have said to me elsewhere already) is logical decoding or replication. The difference there is that the replication stream *is* guaranteed to be in playback, commit order.

The notes above are a thought experiment(ish). If St. Dijkstra, gave us anything, it's that we can, and should, use thought experiments to reason about concurrency issues. If I've mis-reasoned, overlooked something, etc., please answer or comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clear use case for sequences.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION con_id_update() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
  BEGIN
    new.con_id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME, 'con_id'));
    RETURN new;
  END;
$$;

CREATE TABLE example (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  con_id serial NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER con_id BEFORE UPDATE ON example
EXECUTE FUNCTION con_id_update();
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Only just saw your answer now. Yes, what you describe works to provide an auto-incrementing number on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, and your code example is nice and compact. But, I *don't* think that these numbers are possible to rely on for commit-order replay, which is another way of describing what I'm after. As far as i can tell, the only way to do that in PG is through logical decoding/logical replication. If I've got the wrong, I'd be super happy to know about it.

Comment: @MorrisdeOryx your question is unclear. For example, you mentioned using timestamps would be functional, but that would have the same commit-order problem as numeric sequences. Yes, you need to either put them in several table queues for processing, set their numbers from a single process after commit, or use logical replication.

Comment: I'm unclear how a queue applies here, unless your idea is to push through all CUD actions through a single pipe. Logical replication more-or-less achieves that reliably and efficiently. Also, key question: Are sequence numbers *guaranteed* to reflect commit order? In a multi-process/multi-transaction envrionemnt, I don't see how it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the jumps in the sequences is that you have created a default value provider in your table.

***con_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('test_con_ids_sequence')***

Now your first 10 operations (id values 1-10) are just insert operations and you are not providing any value for the con_id column. So the default trigger will increment the sequence to 10 without any problem.

-- Add ten records, IDs 1-10, con_ids 1-10.
INSERT INTO public.test_con_ids (id)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

**Result for test_con_ids_sequence and con_id value:**

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 1 and insert is successful for value 1
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 2 and insert is successful for value 2
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 3 and insert is successful for value 3
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 4 and insert is successful for value 4
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 5 and insert is successful for value 5
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 6 and insert is successful for value 6
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 7 and insert is successful for value 7
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 8 and insert is successful for value 8
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 9 and insert is successful for value 9
test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 10 and insert is successful for value 10

The interesting thing starts when you insert the values 1-5 again and the insert statement throws the conflict for ids and now it tries to update the rows and your manual triggers come in role.

**Even though your transaction throws the error the sequence doesn't rollback it's next evaluated value**

Because of this behavior when the insert fails for value 1, the sequence value is already increased by 1 i.e. 11.
Now update is also using the same sequence to set the value of con_id so you get the 12 now. The same goes for each insert.

INSERT INTO public.test_con_ids (id)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE set id = EXCLUDED.id;

**Result for test_con_ids_sequence and con_id value:**

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 11 but insert failed for value 1

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 12 and updated successfully for value 1

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 13 but inserts failed for value 2

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 14 and updated successfully for value 2

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 15 but inserts failed for value 3

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 16 and updated successfully for value 3

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 17 but inserts failed for value 4

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 18 and updated successfully for value 4

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 19 but inserts failed for value 5

test_con_ids_sequence incremented to 20 and updated successfully for value 5